# How to run python script on Jupyter in the terminal?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter

I want to execute one python script in Jupyter, but I don't want to use the web browser (IPython Interactive terminal), I want to run a single command in the Linux terminal to load & run the python script, so that I can get the output from Jupyter.

I tried to run `jupyter notebook %run <my_script.py>`, but it seems jupyter can't recognize `%run` variable.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `jupyter console -i` command to run an interactive jupyter session in your terminal. From there you can run `import <my_script.py>`. Do note that this is not the intended use case of either jupyter or the notebook environment. You should run scripts using your normal python interpreter instead.

Comment: “this is not the intended use case of either jupyter or the notebook environment” who says that?

Comment: It is not an explicit statement, but the jupyter notebook runs as a web server locally, accessible in port 8888, to be operated in a web browser session.

Answer (score 3):

The `jupyter_client` package has a `jupyter run` command since [v5.0](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/7cfd766b067a2972f9e33ee1d687fa2bc72bb518/setup.py#L93), so you can just do:

```
jupyter run my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to run an interactive jupyter session in your terminal.

> jupyter notebook